# Error Showing While Running Pentaho Data Integrator Community Edition on OSX

Tags: macos, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

While running spoon.sh from my Mac OS I found following error:

[image: error]

After a long time spoon open but there is no option in **Design** or **Transformation**.

I am using OSX 10.13.5

Comment: What do you call  long time ?

Answer (score 0):

This is errors which Pentaho considers as normal and nice in the log. The error is coming from else were.

Are the PENTAHO_JAVA and PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME variables defined? To check run the command set-pentaho-env.sh after having uncommented the two last lines.

`${PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME}/java.exe -version` and `${PENTAHO_JAVA} -version` should give you a java with a version at least 1.8.